# Saving checkbox state using ng-change AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

I want to save the state of a checklist whenever the user opens/closes the application.

This is the first time I use checkboxes in AngularJs/Ionic, and I am not sure how to do this.

**HTML**

```
 <ion-checkbox class="recup checkbox-balanced"  ng-change="save(0)" ng-model="objc[0]">
      Récupéré ton badge
    </ion-checkbox>

    <ion-checkbox class="recup checkbox-balanced"  ng-change="save(1)" ng-model="objc[1]">
      Récupéré ton PC
    </ion-checkbox>

    <ion-checkbox class="recup checkbox-balanced"  ng-change="save(2)" ng-model="objc[2]">
      Visité les locaux
    </ion-checkbox>
```

**JS**

```
.controller('prem-jourController', function ($scope, localStorageService){

defaultValsJ= [false, false, false, false];
var EngObj=localStorageService.get("StoredCheck");
if(!EngObj)
{
    $scope.objc=defaultValsJ;
}
else {
    $scope.objc=EngObj;
}

$scope.save=function(val) {

    $scope.objc[val]=!$scope.objc[val];
    localStorageService.set("StoredCheck", $scope.objc);
}
});
```

The states are saved, but the checkboxes are not clickable anymore and I don't have errors.

Comment: In which case Checkboxes are not clickable when you open app at second time or when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong in the way you save your change. 
Each time, when you click on checkbox, it is changed. Method save called then model change value. Model is two-way binding so your checkbox in uncheck/check again.

That why you can not see checkbox change status.

Change this line to fix:

```
$scope.objc[val]=!$scope.objc[val];
```